# Конвертация времени в Golang

Tags: golang

Ребят кто знает как перевести время в формате RFC3339 (2012-11-01T22:08:41+00:00) в секунды?

Я нашел такую штуку но это не совсем то:

```
t, _ := time.Parse(
    time.RFC3339,
    "2012-11-01T22:08:41+00:00")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.UTC().Unix()` - хехе всего то)